# Entity Framework Error message MYSQL, works on the local machine not when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am having trouble with Entity Framework.
I created a data model and everything seems to work fine on my local debug machine but when I publish i get the following message

System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The store provider factory type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that implements this interface. at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.InitializeProviderManifest(Action`3 addError) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.OnProviderManifestTokenNotification(String token, Action`3 addError) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleProviderManifestTokenAttribute(XmlReader reader) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleAttribute(XmlReader reader) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseAttribute(XmlReader reader) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleTopLevelSchemaElement(XmlReader reader) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.InternalParse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation) at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreItemCollectionLoader.LoadItemCollection(StoreMetadataEntry entry) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a library version thing. What version of each server and library are you running on dev and on production?

Comment: The  server is on the cloud/shared host, but I am putting in my dll mysql.data.dll

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MySQL data provider is not compatible with EF. Are you using [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html) connector ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone.
There I another DLL that needs to be added `MySql.Data.Entity.dll`